# Could someone articulate the uses of type safety for me?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm using type safety to sanitize strings, but I would like more uses articulated.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? This is like asking "Could someone articulate the uses of safety for me?", and specializing the answer to a particular kind of safety: type safety. Safety isn't something that has "uses", per se, though it is certainly useful.

Comment: Come on guys. This is definitely a real question. If we must close it, can we at least move it to programmers.SE? Speaking of which, there is some good discussion at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/59606/is-type-safety-worth-the-trade-offs

Comment: Since 4 other people besides myself liked hammar's answer to my poorly worded question, I'll not delete it. Plus MatrixFrog gave a good re-direct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Yesod web framework](http://www.yesodweb.com/) has several great examples of how type safety can be used to great benefit in real world code.

- [Type-safe URLs](http://www.yesodweb.com/home/snoyberg/blogs/2011/08/shakespeare/new-shakespeare-chapter/shakespearean-templates/type-safe-urls.dita) prevent links on your site from getting broken, as changing or removing a route without updating the templates where it is used will result in a compile-time error.
- Using separate data types for HTML prevents a lot of common XSS vulnerabilities by ensuring that failing to sanitize user input is a type error.
- Their approach to type safe [localization](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2011/05/non-poly-hamlet-i18n) avoids many common issues with translating to languages with different word orders, different pluralization rules and so on, and again the compiler can warn you if a message lacks a translation.

Comment: Marked right for using my favorite web framework as an example! If I could mark Dietrich's answer too, I would.

Answer (score 5):

Sure!

```
Baghdad :: City

launchMissilesAt :: City -> IO ()

fibonacci :: Integer -> Integer
```

By the rules of type safety, we know that `fibonacci` can't launch missiles at Baghdad.  (Note that `unsafePerformIO` is marked as "unsafe" for a reason -- it can violate type safety.  Use with caution!)

Comment: Nice example, unless you use The Function That Must Not Be Named...

Comment: @FUZxxl: I assume you are talking about the functions (there are several) that explicitly violate type safety.  Type safety cannot guarantee anything when you use a function marked as unsafe -- which is why they are marked as unsafe.

Comment: ...and then there's SafeHaskell to help making sure no (type-)unsafe backdoor was used... :-)